# Quais os pontos positivos de utilizar View Engine Aspx no lugar de Razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webforms, razor

Ao pesquisar sobre `ASP.Net MVC`, sempre encontrei todos os exemplos de `views` com `Razor` (não lembro exatamente se vi algum em aspx) e no passado lembro de que era possível selecionar essa View Engine na criação de uma nova aplicação web (não lembro a versão do Visual Studio).

Daí me vieram as dúvidas:

O que leva alguém a utilizar essa `View Engine` com `ASP.Net MVC`?

É possível ter alguma vantagem? Qual?

Nos planos futuros da Microsoft, `Aspx` tem o seu lugar?

Comment: O futuro é melhorar o Razor com Tag Helpers http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNET5VNextWorkInProgressExploringTagHelpers.aspx

Comment: @bigown, muito obrigado pelo Link, este Tag Helper para mim foi a melhor noticia do dia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## O que leva alguém a utilizar essa View Engine com ASP.Net MVC?

Basicamente, o legado. Imagine que você queira portar um grande sistema feito em Web Forms (ASPX) para o MVC. Poupando a camada visual de grandes alterações poupa também os programadores de terem que refazer as telas.

## É possível ter alguma vantagem? Qual?

É. [Em questões de desempenho, o Engine Web Forms é mais rápido](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/91JM151212-Difference-Between-Razor-View-Engine-and-ASPX-View-Engine.html). Além disso, o Razor não tem suporte ao editor de Design do Visual Studio (algumas empresas ainda usam esse editor para fazer páginas), o que dispensa o recurso de saber programar (pelo menos inicialmente) em HTML.

## Nos planos futuros da Microsoft, Aspx tem o seu lugar?

Possivelmente só como legado. É muito oneroso para a Microsoft manter o editor de Design do Visual Studio, então a ideia é que esta parte seja pragmaticamente descontinuada.

Comment: Não acho que ele esteja se referindo ao WebForms, por mais que a gente costume associar a extensão *.aspx a ele. Apesar do ASPX View Engine ter a mesma extensão do WebForms e possuir o mesmo estilo, não é possivel reaproveitar um WebForms de forma tão direta.

Comment: Concordo, mas entre realizar uma migração para ASPX e para Razor, a mudança para ASPX é muito menos onerosa.